# NodeJS Express remove all session from same user

Tags: node.js, session, express

I wonder what is the best way to remove all sessions of a user that is connecting ?
What I want to do, is to logout all old sessions on all devices when a user logs in a new device.

I couldn't find any accurate answers.

Many thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

A part of the answer for MongoDB connections store is here : https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/201